# warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

Tags: opengl

I don't know what is the problem here .. anybody can help me the source code is [Hello Triangle](http://www.learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle)

Comment: It's proper StackOverflow etiquette to post the code in verbatim into the question and not link it.

Answer (score 3):

This warning is emitted by the MSVC++ linker when a library using a different C runtime than your main executable uses is linked into your executable. It can also happen if libraries with different C runtime libraries are linked. In general this doesn't pose a showstopper problem, but if it breaks, it usually breaks in spectacular ways.

The usual solution for static libraries is to build the libraries without linking in a C runtime and let them depend on the C runtime of the executable they're linked into. For dynamic libraries things however get complicated.

Comment: This is misleading. How can a static library be built without a CRT?

Comment: @Dan: This might sound somewhat tautological, but… well… by building it without a CRT. Static libraries effectively are nothing else than an archive (not unlike zip, or tar), of several `.obj` files, i.e. what's produced by a compiler. And the compilation artifact of a compiler can be built without depending on a specific CRT and the only "external" requirement is for some CRT being also linked in the final executable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. When I attempted to build a static library without a CRT recently, I found that MSVC included one anyway, and this gave me issues linking down the line due to conflicting runtimes.

Comment: @Dan: If you look at the `LIB` tool's reference, you'll notice, that options regarding CRT are suspiciously absent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/lib-reference?view=msvc-170 and if you look at the options selecting the CRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library you'll notice that they're part of the linker, i.e. the tool that creates PE files (`.exe`, `.dll`, …), However take note that the COFF objects inside a static library may specify a CRT to use (may be explicitly set during compile time).

Comment: What I found was that dumpbin of the static library contained the linker directive `/FAILIFMISMATCH:RuntimeLibrary=MT_StaticRelease`, even though I had specifically built it with no Runtime Library set. Do you know where this could have come from? By the way, this relates to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659640/lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary-value-mt-staticrelease-doesnt . The only solution that I could find was to set the CRT explicitly when building the library.