# Understanding warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

When building my Visual Studio project, I get a linker warning:

> warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

As I understand it, this warning arises from a program including 2 different versions of the C runtime library.

My program's Runtime Library is set to "**Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)**". This matches the runtime library of all the dynamically-linked libraries in use (for example SDL2, as described [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/FAQWindows#when_using_visual_c_i_get_link_errors_relating_to_msvcrt.lib_or_libc)).

I am also using a couple of static libraries, which I have compiled with *no* CRT (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703199/1624459)), however the linker warning still occurs.

How can I identify which libraries are conflicting here?

Comment: Perhaps use a temporary project and add libraries 1 at a time until you get the error.  There is also a [`/VERBOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages?view=msvc-170) linker option which may provide more info,

Comment: Great suggestions! I was able to narrow down the problematic library (GLEW static), and it turns out I hadn't correctly rebuilt it without a CRT.